# Syntax error for the code found in a tutorial?

Tags: c++

I was learning to do a program online and found this solution and I wanted to execute and learn from it.

I am keep getting syntax error, can someone help with formatting it? I tried but couldn't understand the code that much to see where we need to provide indentation etc.,

I couldn't find a python example online for that question, I could only find c++ answer.

```
class Node {

public:

virtual int Compute() = 0;

inline void SetLeft(Node* left) {

left_ = left;

}

inline void SetRight(Node* right) {

right_ = right;

}

protected:

Node* left_ = nullptr;

Node* right_ = nullptr;

};

class SumNode : public Node {

public:

inline int Compute() override {

return left_->Compute() + right_->Compute();

}

};

class SubNode : public Node {

public:

inline int Compute() override {

return left_->Compute() - right_->Compute();

}

};

class MulNode : public Node {

public:

inline int Compute() override {

return left_->Compute() * right_->Compute();

}

};

class NumNode : public Node {

public:

NumNode(int num) : num_(num) {}

inline int Compute() override {

return num_;

}

private:

int num_;

};

class Solution {

public:

vector<int> diffWaysToCompute(string expression) {

  

vector<Node*> nodes;

  

// parse the expression

for(int i = 0; i < expression.size(); ++i) {

  

switch(expression[i]) {

case '+':

nodes.emplace_back(new SumNode());

break;

case '-':

nodes.emplace_back(new SubNode());

break;

case '*':

nodes.emplace_back(new MulNode());

break;

default:

int num = 0;

while(expression[i] >= '0' && expression[i] <= '9') {

num = num * 10 + expression[i] - '0';

++i;

}

--i;

nodes.emplace_back(new NumNode(num));

break;

}

}

  

vector<Node*> trees = GenerateAllTrees(nodes, 0, nodes.size() - 1);

  

for(Node* node : nodes) {

delete node;

}

  

vector<int> results;

for(Node* tree : trees) {

results.emplace_back(tree->Compute());

delete tree;

}

return results;

  

}

  

vector<Node*> GenerateAllTrees(const vector<Node*> nodes, int beg, int end) {

  

if(beg == end) {

return {new NumNode(nodes[beg]->Compute())};

}

  

vector<Node*> results;

  

for(int i = beg; i <= end; i++) {

  

// assuming the expression is well formed, operators will be in odd positions

if((i & 1) == 0) continue;

  

vector<Node*> left_trees = GenerateAllTrees(nodes, beg, i - 1);

vector<Node*> right_trees = GenerateAllTrees(nodes, i + 1, end);

  

for(Node* left : left_trees) {

for(Node* right : right_trees) {

nodes[i]->SetLeft(left);

nodes[i]->SetRight(right);

Node* result = new NumNode(nodes[i]->Compute());

results.emplace_back(result);

}

}

for(Node* t : left_trees) {

delete t;

}

for(Node* t : right_trees) {

delete t;

}

  

}

  

return results;

   }

};
```

Comment: Please format your code so we can read it, and please link to the tutorial you're using so we can see it for ourselves.

Comment: @Dai https://www.chegg.com/homework-help/questions-and-answers/business-problem-g-gupshup-message-aggregator-means-large-number-clients-wish-send-message-q85061758

Comment: What kind of a website is that meant to be?

Comment: @Dai I wanted to execute and try converting it back to python. I don't know that's the only website which was providing the solution.

Comment: @Dai Its a online study portal.

Comment: As long as you add `#include <string>` and `#include <vector>` at the beginning, it compiles just fine.  If you are using `g++`, you'll need `--std=c++11`.

Comment: Where do I need to add #include <string> and #include <vector>? Can you paste a demo example?

Comment: That online study portal is not doing a good job. Demand your money back.

Comment: No, those are exactly the same as Python `import` statements.  They go at the beginning, because you are using `vector` and `string` types.  You'll also need `using namespace std;` after those two lines.

Comment: If you need to learn C++ start here https://www.learncpp.com/, or more specifically : https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/statements-and-the-structure-of-a-program/.
However you said you where looking for the solution to a programming problem, what was that problem, something with expressions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to import the modules you are using, exactly like Python, except the syntax is different:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Node {
    public:
...
```

And because it is using `emplace_back`, if you are using `g++`, you'll need to specify `-std=c++11` on the command line.

Also, you need to understand this is not a runnable example.  These are just classes you could use in your own code.  To run this, you'll need to supply a `main()` function.  Maybe:

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    Solution s;
    vector<int> result = s.diffWaysToCompute( "3+9*7-16" );
    for( auto i : result )
        cout << i << "\n";
}
```

Comment: Okay sir, can you tell a example of the main() function, how I can write it. What modification do I need to make sir?

Comment: What good is this going to do you?  If you are trying to learn C++, you don't jump right into the middle.  You need to learn about `#include` and `main` before diving into classes and inheritance.

Comment: Actually sir, I want to learn c++ enough to convert this particular code to python and learn. Thank you soo much. Let me try these changes and see if it executes.